# How do I trigger a data refresh on my FlyoutContentTemplate view model when navigating back from my add page?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm, xamarin.forms.shell

I am building a Xamarin Forms application using Shell in which I am not building your typical flyout. I have created a template each for the header, footer and content. The content contains data which is fetched from a database.

I'm defining these in my app.xaml file.

```
<Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="FlyoutFooterTemplate" Value="{DataTemplate common:FlyoutFooterTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="FlyoutHeaderTemplate" Value="{DataTemplate common:FlyoutHeaderTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="FlyoutContentTemplate" Value="{DataTemplate common:FlyoutContentTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

I have created the FlyoutContentTemplate as a RefreshView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RefreshView 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InFlight.ViewModels.Common"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:InFlight.Core.Models;assembly=InFlight.Core"  
    x:Class="InFlight.Views.Common.FlyoutContentTemplate"
    x:DataType="local:FlyoutContentTemplateViewModel"
    Command="{Binding LoadFlightsCommand}"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <CollectionView    
        ItemsSource="{Binding Flights}"
        SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Flight">
                    <Label Text="{Binding CallSign}"
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource LabelMedium}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding FlightNotes}" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource LabelSmall}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <CollectionView.Footer>
            <Button Command="{Binding AddFlightCommand}" Text="Add Flight" />
        </CollectionView.Footer>
    </CollectionView>
</RefreshView>
```

The code behind simply sets the BindingContext.

```cs
using InFlight.ViewModels.Common;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace InFlight.Views.Common
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FlyoutContentTemplate : RefreshView
    {
        readonly FlyoutContentTemplateViewModel viewModel;

        public FlyoutContentTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = viewModel = new FlyoutContentTemplateViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

The view model is fairly simple and handles the LoadFlightsCommand triggered by the RefreshView and the navigation to the AddEditFlightPage.

```cs
using InFlight.Core.Models;
using InFlight.Core.Respositories;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace InFlight.ViewModels.Common
{
    public class FlyoutContentTemplateViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
        public Command LoadFlightsCommand { get; }
        public Command AddFlightCommand { get; }
        readonly IFlightRepository flightRepository;

        public FlyoutContentTemplateViewModel()
        {
            flightRepository = DependencyService.Get<IFlightRepository>();
            
            Flights = new ObservableCollection<Flight>();
            LoadFlightsCommand = new Command(ExecuteLoadFlightsCommand);
            AddFlightCommand = new Command(async () => await OnAddFlightCommand());

            ExecuteLoadFlightsCommand();
        }

        private async Task OnAddFlightCommand()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("AddEditFlightPage");
            Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;
        }

        private void ExecuteLoadFlightsCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                Flights.Clear();
                var flts = flightRepository.GetFlights();

                foreach (var flight in flts)
                {
                    Flights.Add(flight);
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This all seems to work well, but at the moment I need to pull to refresh in order to trigger the `LoadFlightsCommand`.

The issue is that I want to trigger the data refresh when navigating back from my add page. I've seen posts where people tap into the `OnAppearing` event in order to trigger the refresh, but as I am using a template and refresh view, I don't see how I can do that.

Have I maybe taken the wrong approach and using Shell for a purpose it shouldn't be used for?

I'm thinking that the solution probably involves the events of the shell itself?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please simplify your post/code to the essential (maybe create a reroduction repo) by focusing on what is the issue exactly ? I have tested your code and when i pull refresh the `ExecuteLoadFlightsCommand` got triggered as expected

Comment: where/how do you register the route for `AddEditFlightPage`?

Comment: @Cfun Thank you for taking the time out to respond. I'm not going to lie, my registering of routes is a bit messy at the moment and I need to read up on this area. I've been working on other functionality but need to clean this up. For the `AddEditFlightPage`, I am registering the route in my AppShell constructor `Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(AddEditFlightPage), typeof(AddEditFlightPage));`. I've taken a look at your answer and will try to see if it works. The only thing I was wary of was whether storing a reference to the vm in AppShell is seen as good MVVM practice? Not saying it isn't btw.

Comment: You're welcome, I don't see this as a break of the mvvm pattern, which mvvm pattern rule this design possibly breaking? Please let me know if it works for you or you had some issues implementing it

Comment: I'm just starting out with Xamarin and MVVM and I'm just a little paranoid that I'm following best practice. Having thought about it, you are right, it doesn't seem to be bad practice at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First Approach

I don't have the full picture on how you are defining your `Shell`'s routes/navigation, but I believe what you are trying to achieve could be done using Shell event `OnNavigated` or `OnNavigating`.

- First thing, Shell (AppShell.xaml.cs) need to have access to the instance of your `FlyoutContentTemplateViewModel` in roder to call the method `ExecuteLoadFlightsCommand()` from there.
- Turn the accessibility of `ExecuteLoadFlightsCommand()` to public.

**AppShell.xaml.cs**

```
  public FlyoutContentTemplateViewModel flyoutContentTemplateViewModel;

    public AppShell()
    {
        flyoutContentTemplateViewModel = new();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

  protected override void OnNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
    {
        var previousRouteString = args?.Previous?.Location?.OriginalString;
        var currentRouteString = args?.Current?.Location?.OriginalString;
        
        if (previousRouteString != null && previousRouteString.Contains("[DEPENDS ON YOUR ROUTES NAME]") &&
            currentRouteString.Contains("[DEPENDS ON YOUR ROUTES NAME]"))
        {
           flyoutContentTemplate.ExecuteLoadFlightsCommand();
        }

        base.OnNavigated(args);
    }
```

In your `FlyoutContentTemplate()`, use the same ViewModel instance from the field that we have added in your AppShell.

```
public FlyoutContentTemplate()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   BindingContext = viewModel = (Shell.Current as AppShell).flyoutContentTemplateViewModel;
}
```

---

#### Second Approach

If you don't want to store your VM in your AppShell then you might use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).

- Extract an interface from your `FlyoutContentTemplateViewModel`: on visual studio select the class name, right click, in the menu click "Quick Actions and refactoring", after that click "Extract interface", VS will generate an interface called `IFlyoutContentTemplateViewModel`:

```
 public interface IFlyoutContentTemplateViewModel
    {
        Command AddFlightCommand { get; }
        ObservableCollection<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
        bool IsBusy { get; }
        Command LoadFlightsCommand { get; }

        Task OnAddFlightCommand()
        void ExecuteLoadFlightsCommand();
    }
```

- **FlyoutContentTemplate.xaml.cs**

```
public FlyoutContentTemplate()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = viewModel = new FlyoutContentTemplateViewModel();
    DependencyService.RegisterSingleton<IFlyoutContentTemplateViewModel>(viewModel);
}
```

- **AppShell.xaml.cs**

```
...
if (previousRouteString != null && previousRouteString.Contains("[DEPENDS ON YOUR ROUTES NAME]") &&
    currentRouteString.Contains("[DEPENDS ON YOUR ROUTES NAME]"))
 {
        DependencyService.Resolve<IFlyoutContentTemplateViewModel>()?.ExecuteLoadFlightsCommand();
 }
```

---

#### Third Approach

Calling  `ExecuteLoadFlightsCommand()` from `OnDisappearing()` of `AddEditFlightPage`, instead of `AppShell.OnNavigated()`.

**AddEditFlightPage.xaml.cs**

```
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        (DependencyService.Resolve<IFlyoutContentTemplateViewModel>())?.ExecuteLoadFlightsCommand();
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }
```

Comment: I agree with you the solution involves the Shell's event

Comment: I have tried to implement the above code and ran into a couple of issues. I had to change the if statement slightly to handle the previous route string being null. `if ((previousRouteString != null && previousRouteString.Contains("AddEditFlightPage")) && currentRouteString.Contains("ItemsPage"))` The main problem is I can't seem to reference the public view model property in my AppShell.xaml.cs when assigning the BindingContext.

Comment: Sorry it was  typo from my part it should be `BindingContext = viewModel = Shell.Current.flyoutContentTemplateViewModel ` and not `BindingContext = viewModel = Shell.Current.flyoutContentTemplate;`, check my edit i have corrected it. Good catch for testing if previousRouteString is null :)

Comment: No problem, but I had already noticed that and was already trying `flyoutContentTemplateViewModel`. It gives me the following error, but I'm missing where I am making my mistake. Error CS1061 'Shell' does not contain a definition for 'flyoutContentTemplateViewModel' and no accessible extension method 'flyoutContentTemplateViewModel' accepting a first argument of type 'Shell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: code edited, check with `BindingContext = viewModel = (Shell.Current as AppShell).flyoutContentTemplateViewModel;`

Comment: I think the problem with this approach is that Shell.Current is null at the time when the BindingContext is being set in my code behind. I get the following error and assume that it is because Xamarin is still in the process of building out the shell. `**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:** 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'` Maybe I need to rethink my approach and tackle it from a different angle i.e. not using flyoutContentTemplate approach. Maybe I should fetch the data as part of the AppShell code behind and just populate Items.

Comment: `Shell.Current` shouldn't be null at the time you set the bindingcontext (AppShell class is being called just after App.xaml.cs which is the root startup of the program), I believe the error is something else. A part from that have you checked my 3rd approach it is not involving Shell?

Comment: So sorry, didn't even see that you had went out of your way to create additional approaches. Let me digest them and give them a go before I get back to you. I really appreciate all the guidance.

Comment: If the solution helps consider marking it as answer ,it is helpful to others who's facing the same problem .

Comment: @Cfun Thank you so much for your help. I went with Option 3 in the end and created a property on my vm which allowed me to determine whether a save had actually taken place before refreshing.